# Database restore seems trigering offline index build

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a strange behaviour with Sql server 2008 R2 SP2.

First I restore a backup of database.
Then I launch this command

```
DBCC OPENTRAN
```

And I get this response:

```
Transaction information for database 'Pitming'.

Oldest active transaction:
    SPID (server process ID): 34s
    UID (user ID) : -1
    Name          : offline index build
    LSN           : (4082671:527:134)
    Start time    : Jul 17 2014  8:59:38:107AM
    SID           : 0x0
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
```

then it's impossible to delete the database I always get an error saying the database is in use. 
It's also impossible to truncate the log

This behaviour is not present in SQL 2005

Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment until my reputation is higher so forgive me if this "answer" is off the mark. If you are restoring to SQL2008 R2 a backup that was created with an earlier version of SQL Server the problem may be with full-text indexes. If this is the case try setting your server's Full Text Upgrade Option to 1 (Reset) before the restore. Then rebuild the full-text indexes after the database is upgraded to 2008 R2.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858(v=sql.105).aspx

"After you restore a SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2000 database to SQL Server 2008 R2, the database becomes available immediately and is then automatically upgraded. If the database has full-text indexes, the upgrade process either imports, resets, or rebuilds them, depending on the setting of the upgrade_option server property."